# ASP input Class Does not activate JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, class

I have two inputs in an ASP page:

```
<input type="text" class="arrivalDate form inp compare_prices_fields datepicker total_price_fields price_list_fields allRows" id="calc_arrdate_group_0" value="" style="width: 95px" rbo_id="ArrivalDate" />
<input type="text" class="departureDate form inp compare_prices_fields datepicker total_price_fields price_list_fields allRows" id="calc_depdate_group_0" value="" style="width: 95px" rbo_id="DepartureDate" />
```

On my ASP page i have this JavaScript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
.
.
    $(".compare_prices_fields").change(function () {
        comparePrices();
    });
```

While when I change the text in the first input it activates the function, it doesn't happen when I change the second one.

I tried adding the class "compare_prices_fields" to other elements it it works fine on everyone but the input I need.

Can someone give me a hand on what to change in my code?

Comment: Your code works fine. The change attaches to both textboxes when tested. Something else must be going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this problem. I just added the code onblur="comparePrices();" to the problematic element and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The thing when you use it this way with getting the elements with jQuery, you attach your handler only to the first element, if you really want to keep this way, then make sure that you attach this handler to all the elements:

```
$(".captureComment").each(() => {
        this.addEventListener("change", comparePrices);
});
```

Just a suggestion, you could attach your handler directly on every input:

```
<input ... onchange="comparePrices()" />
```

Comment: I tried both your ways and none worked. All the other elements activate the function but this one.

Comment: Sorry, I used wrong selector in the first example, I was testing in my project.
Have you tried with your selector or with mine, because it works for me.

Comment: Whay you say is not correct @zpouip. `$(".compare_prices_fields").change(function () {` will attach to all objects with that class, not just the first.

Comment: @VDWWD You are right, I just tried it myself again.

Comment: I am not sure how it is rendering the elements, what I've noticed that if not all the elements are rendered when ```$(document).ready()``` is triggered, it will not attach this handler.